# Applying a FIR filter to floating point array c#

Tags: filters, c#, finite-impulse-response, floating-point

I have designed using MATLAB a FIR filter with some coefficients.

I have an array that is normalized to -+1. The array is float.

I used this method to apply the FIR to the array but I'm not sure if this is fine:

```
public static float[] FirFilter(float[] b, float[] x)
    {
        int M = b.Length;// b == coffecients of FIR
        int n = x.Length;// x == mySignalSamples
        //y[n]=b0x[n]+b1x[n-1]+....bmx[n-M]
        var y = new float[n];
        for (int yi = 0; yi < n; yi++)
        {
            float t = 0.0f;
            for (int bi = M - 1; bi >= 0; bi--)
            {
                if (yi - bi < 0) continue;

                t += b[bi] * x[yi - bi];
            }
            y[yi] = t;
        }
        //return Convert.ToDouble(y);
        return y;
    }
```

Am I doing that right?

Comment: Questions about getting a specific piece of code to work are off-topic for this site. At a glance it looks reasonable. You should put in a known signal and see if you get what you expect at the output.

Comment: My problem is that after applying this and specograming it back in matlab I get a big reduction in magnitude. For example: from 0 db to -40db in my specific frequency which I want to pass

Comment: Why don't you use Matlab to filter your signal, so you have a reference as to what you should get?

Comment: I use it, but the the plots I get are deferent so I assume something wrong in my code